# How do I bind an ienumerable list item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am attempting to bind a DataGridComboBoxColumn to a list element using dot notation. My list has data, which I can see in the code behind, but my ComboBox is blank.

I have tried numerous versions of binding dot notation levels.

Here's my code behind...

```
            List<DatabaseProperty> dbList = new List<DatabaseProperty>();

            foreach(Database db in srv1.Databases)
            {
                DatabaseProperty newDB = new DatabaseProperty();
                newDB.DBName = db.Name.ToString();

                // Get the DB's users
                //List<DBUser> dbUserList = new List<DBUser>();

                for (int i = 0; i < srv1.Logins.Count; i++)
                {
                    // DatabaseProperty class contains a DBUser enumerable list
                    DBUser newdbUser = new DBUser();
                    //newDB.DBUserList[i].UserName = srv1.Logins[i].Name;
                    newdbUser.UserName = srv1.Logins[i].Name;

                    newDB.DBUserList.Add(newdbUser);
                }

                dbList.Add(newDB);
            }
```

And the WPF...

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgServers" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,24,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="237" Width="397" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding dbPropsList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="DBname" Binding="{Binding DBName}" />

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="DB Users" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DBUserList.DBUser.UserName }" >

                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: How and where is the `DBUserList` property defined in your example?

Answer (score 1):

First create a public property to be able to bind:

```
public DatabaseProperty MyNewBindableDB {get;set;}

List<DatabaseProperty> dbList = new List<DatabaseProperty>();    
        foreach(Database db in srv1.Databases)
        {
            DatabaseProperty newDB = new DatabaseProperty();
            newDB.DBName = db.Name.ToString();

            // Get the DB's users
            //List<DBUser> dbUserList = new List<DBUser>();

            for (int i = 0; i < srv1.Logins.Count; i++)
            {
                // DatabaseProperty class contains a DBUser enumerable list
                DBUser newdbUser = new DBUser();
                //newDB.DBUserList[i].UserName = srv1.Logins[i].Name;
                newdbUser.UserName = srv1.Logins[i].Name;

                newDB.DBUserList.Add(newdbUser);
            }

            dbList.Add(newDB);
        }

        MyNewBindableDB = dbList.FirstOrDefault(); //gets one list from your 
        //list of <DatabaseProperty>.
```

Now your code should be like:

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
    Header="DB Users"       
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyNewBindableDB.DBUserList}"
    SelectedValuePath="UserName" 
    DisplayMemberPath="UserName">
  </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

You could also create a property of type 'DBUserList' and bind to it.

More information: 
[DataGridComboBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I tried this  <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Users" ItemsSource="{Binding DBUserList}" DisplayMemberPath="UersName" />

Comment: @DougClavell In order to work properly, you need to Correctly bind the object properties into your gridComboBox, could you update your post with a more clear description of your DBUser object?

Comment: class DBUser
    {
        private string userName;
      //  private string login;
        
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return userName; }
            set { userName = value; }
        }

Comment: @DougClavell the object newDB.DBUserList is the one that needs to be the data source of your DataGridComboBox, therefore, you should have a public property of the type: DatabaseProperty, thus you will be able to bind to your DataGridComboBox. I will edit my post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up on DataGridComboBoxColumn.

```
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DBUserList}" Text="{Binding UserName}" 
                     DisplayMemberPath="UserName" IsEditable="True"></ComboBox>
         </DataTemplate>
```

Seems I needed both TEXT and DisplayMemberPath attributes to pull this off.